# Java socket test returning null value

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple server and client program in Eclipse using java but whenever I run the program both consoles output null. Im not sure why this is happening. I read that a common problem is that I've already created an instance of the server and am trying to create another instance but I'm sure thats not the problem. I also read that I might not have root access and need to use a port that is higher than 1024, so I did and I still have the same error.

Server code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Socket_Server_Side {
   public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
      Socket_Server_Side server = new Socket_Server_Side();
      server.run();
   }

   public void run() throws Exception {
      ServerSocket SvrSocket = new ServerSocket(1025);
      SvrSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
      Socket socket = SvrSocket.accept();
      InputStreamReader Ir = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(Ir);

      String message = Br.readLine();
      System.out.println(message);

      if (message != null) {
          System.out.println("Message succesfully sent and recieved!");
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.PrintStream;
 import java.net.Socket;

 public class Socket_Client_Side {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
       Socket_Client_Side client = new Socket_Client_Side();
       client.run();
     }

    public void run() throws Exception {
       Socket socket2 = new Socket("localhost", 1025);
       PrintStream Ps = new PrintStream(socket2.getOutputStream());
       Ps.println("Hello Server");
       InputStreamReader Ir = new InputStreamReader(socket2.getInputStream());
       BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(Ir);

       String message = Br.readLine();
       System.out.println(message);
     }
 }
```

Comment: There is no 'socket test' here. Your client is **printing** null because it is reading from a connection which has already been closed by the peer without anything having been sent.

Comment: In spite of the flaws, I'm not sure why this is a terrible question...it's got easy-to-compile code and is at least symptomatic of someone whose never programmed with sockets before.

Comment: Some remarks on your code: class names in Java should use [PascalCase](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase) and variables shoud use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

Comment: @EJP The client may read from a closed socket, but that does not explain why the server is not receiving the data send by the client.

Comment: @Turing85 Is *that* what the problem is? Your prior description is impossible. The server code does not output null. Clearly only the *client* is printing null.  NB the client. Is *not* reading from a closed socket: it is reading from a closed *connection.*

Comment: @Makato The problem description does not agree with the code, and the title doesn't begin to make sense.

Comment: @EJP **[...] both consoles output null.* I myself cannot reproduce this behaviour (server-side is working partially). You could just have written that the server-side is not printing `null` for you. And sorry for the misuse. You are of course right, the connection has been reset.

Comment: Stop misrepresenting me. Three times now. I *did* say that the server console wasn't printing null, and I *didn't* say the connection had been reset. I said it had been *closed*. I *also* explained the only problem that this code actually manifests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, your code works fine.  The reason that your client is printing `null` is due to it not receiving any input *itself*.

Let's describe the scenario in which you're communicating at a high level.

You have two programs; the server and the client.  The server is actively listening for any input to it, and the client sends input to the server.  This process is (so far) one-way, and the way we have the code structured, we are only ever writing anything to the server.

Now, you have two channels of communication with a socket:  input and output.  Recall that we are sending data across to the server, and the server isn't sending any data to the client.  This means:

- The server should only care about **input**, and not anything to do with **output**.
- The client should only care about **output**, and not anything to do with **input**.

That said, this code in your client is superfluous:

```
InputStreamReader Ir = new InputStreamReader(socket2.getInputStream());
BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(Ir);

String message = Br.readLine();
System.out.println(message);
```

The reason for this is that your client does not have any input coming in to it, so any messages that *did* suddenly show up would be a strange thing indeed.

Comment: Thank you for this advice, if I removed these lines of code, would my program work as expected?

Comment: You wouldn't get `null` from the client anymore (the server doesn't print `null` in my environment).

Comment: The server doesn't print null in any environment. It contains a test to prevent it from doing that.